# How to set and use includeTransactions with Authorize.net PHP SDK?

Tags: php, authorize.net

I and others have been working with the Authorize.net automatic recurring billing (ARB) portion of the API, trying to retrieve recent transactions related to a subscription.

The documentation (https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#recurring-billing-get-subscription-status) for ARBGetSubscriptionRequest states that there is an optional parameter includeTransactions that will return recent transactions associated with the subscription.

The PHP SDK seems to be missing the parameter includeTransactions.

In my call to Authorize.net, the following results in an error:

`$subscription->setIncludeTransactions(true);`

Has anyone managed to get it working?

Related github issues: [#120](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/issues/102), [#280](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sdk-php/issues/280)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that includeTransactions support has been implemented in the underlying Authorize.net API; however, the PHP SDK is woefully out of date. And no sample code has been forthcoming from Authorize.net (earliest request is from June 2016)

So, for my purposes, I forked the PHP SDK:
https://github.com/sjordan1975/sdk-php

I implemented get ARB Transaction from Get Subscription sufficient for what I needed.

Specifically, I modified the following 4 files:

```
lib/net/authorize/api/contract/v1/ARBGetSubscriptionRequest.php
lib/net/authorize/api/contract/v1/ARBSubscriptionMaskedType.php
lib/net/authorize/api/yml/v1/ARBGetSubscriptionRequest.yml
lib/net/authorize/api/yml/v1/ARBSubscriptionMaskedType.yml
```

Immediately after setting setSubscriptionID in the sample code (https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-php/blob/master/RecurringBilling/get-subscription-status.php) add the following:

`$request->setIncludeTransactions(true);`

Note: I have used TransactionDetailsType whereas I suspect the actual type should be something like ARBTransactionType, but the yaml definition is missing and I have not defined it

The result is for now not all transaction data is populated; HOWEVER, transId IS populated and this is good enough to make an additional API call to get Transaction Details.

Feel free to have at it. Code provided AS IS to the Community. YMMV